# Is there a way to add function calls to knex returning or select methods?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, knex.js, geography, set-returning-functions

I am trying to add a method call ST_ASText to a Geography column to convert it back to a wkt. So I tried doing something like this.

```
activeTrx(TABLE_NAME)
            .returning(['id', 'ST_AsText(polygon_wkt)')
            .insert(values);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik that should work, but you will need to use knex.raw

```
activeTrx(TABLE_NAME)
    .returning([
      'id', 
      knex.raw('ST_AsText(??)', ['polygon_wkt'])
    ])
    .insert(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this. This worked.

```html
activeTrx
        .raw(
            `?
            RETURNING id, ST_AsText(polygon_wkt) as polygon_wkt;`,
            [activeTrx.table(TABLE_NAME).insert(values)],
            )
        .then((result) => {
            return result.rows;
        });
```